# Causal Impact and using multiple control series with their regressors

Tags: time-series, bayesian, inference, causality, causalimpact

Hi all I am analyzing several DMA's for campaign effectiveness using the CausalImpact package by Kay Brodersen. I have data for participants and non-participants INCLUDING their contemporaneous regressors (e.g. Spend dollars, Economic attributes, Google search trend data e.t.c) 
My question is HOW can I use the Control time series "together with their regressors" to evaluate the Participants campaign effectiveness.
The documentation does not include such an example

Comment: This is hard to follow. What are "DMA's"? What "documentation" are you referring to? Are you just asking for help w/ your software / code?

Comment: Hi gung. A DMA is a designated market area in which several of them are test markets and the majority are controls without a marketing intervention. The documentation I am referring to is the package research paper http://research.google.com/pubs/pub41854.html. The question is more about the application of the package and if I can utilize it for multiple control series but also with additional regressors.

Comment: I feel like this message should probably be a comment but I can't seem to post one now :(
I'm working on a similar problem and I'm planning to throw in a few control series AND a few key covariates (macro economics, marketing spending etc.). What method did you end up using for your problem? Would you mind sharing your experience with `CausalImpact` for similar problem? Thanks!